# How to handle windows download popup for IE11 using Selenium Webdriver without using AutoIT

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

While testing on IE11, When I click on the link to download a doc, a new blank window opens up with save and Cancel option popup. I want to hit cancel, Switch back to my current window and continue validation.
Can anyone help me how to handle this without the use of AutoIT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selenium-webdriver with Java then you can use [Sikuli-api](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/).

Just a small introduction: Sikuli is a tool which helps to achive automation task for any software(web/standalone). Base of Sikuli is a Screenshot of the control you would like to interact with.

In your case, it is just matter of 2 buttons. Hence I would not suggest you to use seperate autoIT generated `*.exe` file.
Just take screenshot of OK & Cancel button.

Showing you the sample code here:

```
    import org.sikuli.script.*;
    public class Test {
    
    Screen m_screen;
    SikuliScript m_sikscr;
    @Test
    public void Test1() throws FindFailed
    {
        m_screen=new Screen();
        m_screen.wait((double) 10.0);
        //Click on Cancel button
         m_screen.click(new Pattern("./img/CancelButton.png"));
    }
   }
```

This much should do your task.

Please Note, if at all you decide to use this method, make sure that you handle all Sikuli related dependencies in java project.

Comment: Thanks you for the code. Is there any other way to handle this without using a 3rd party tool?

Comment: I don't think so...because the buttons u are controlling are native OS buttons on which selenium do not have any control..

Answer (score 0):

Try manually at first whether by pressing escape key it dismissing the popup.

if so follow the below code,

```
Robot r = null;
try {
    r = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```